# I want to get only roleId of those data that satisfies the condition (resourceId==3 && canView);

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, reduce

I have this set of data:

```
roles = [{roleId:1,resourceRole:[
{canAdd:true,canUpdate:true,canView:true,canDelete:true,resourceId:1},
{canAdd:true,canUpdate:true,canView:true,canDelete:true,resourceId:2},
{canAdd:false,canUpdate:false,canView:false,canDelete:false,resourceId:3}
]},
{roleId:2,resourceRole:[
{canAdd:true,canUpdate:true,canView:true,canDelete:true,resourceId:1},
{canAdd:false,canUpdate:false,canView:false,canDelete:false,resourceId:2},
{canAdd:false,canUpdate:false,canView:false,canDelete:false,resourceId:3}
]},
{roleId:3,resourceRole:[
{canAdd:true,canUpdate:true,canView:true,canDelete:true,resourceId:1},
{canAdd:false,canUpdate:false,canView:false,canDelete:false,resourceId:2},
{canAdd:true,canUpdate:true,canView:true,canDelete:true,resourceId:3}
]}
];
```

In this case, my output should be [1] because resourceId==3 && canView==true is only in the data with roleId 1 and 3. How can I get this with minimum complexity?

Comment: That's not a valid JS data structure. It should be `resourceId: 1`. What have you tried? A combination of `.filter()`, `.some()` and `.map()` should solve this

Comment: my bad :), corrected my question

Comment: Why would `1` be returned? The entry with `resourceId: 3` has `canView: false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the roles if `resourceId === 3 && canView`, then map the results to get only the roleId:

```js
const result = roles
  .filter(({ resourceRole }) =>
    resourceRole.some(({ resourceId, canView }) => resourceId === 3 && canView)
  )
  .map(({ roleId }) => roleId);
```

It returns only role 3 because is the only one that satisfies the condition `resourceId === 3 && canView`

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-murdock-k70xvp?file=/src/index.js:1545-1549